# What can be a FastCGI client?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, cgi

`fcgiweb` is a server based on FastCGI protocol.

What can be a FastCGI client?  Is a CGI script a FastCGI client, or is a web server (e.g. Nginx) a FastCGI client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

FastCGI is explicitly a protocol for web servers to communicate requests to web applications and receive the responses. I suppose something other than a web server could be a FastCGI client, but it probably wouldn't make much sense.

These days it's not common for web apps to actually use FastCGI, unless they're written in PHP, the interpreter for which includes a FastCGI server. Most other web apps just speak HTTP.